# How can I call function in PHP

Tags: php, function, echo

I have file index.php and there I have this code:

```
echo'
     THIS IS MY SITE
     <ul>
        <li><a href="'.show_one().'">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.show_two().'">TWO</a></li>
     </ul>
';

function show_one(){
   echo "SOMETHING";
} 

function show_two(){
   echo "SOMETHING ELSE";
}
```

Now it'll show:

```
THIS IS MY SITE
SOMETHING
SOMETHING ELSE
```

I want to show text only after click to link. When i first show this site I want to see only THIS IS MY SITE and than when I click to ONE browser show me only SOMETHING. And when i click TWO it'll show me only SOMETHING ELSE.

Comment: Sounds like you probably need to use Ajax, since by the time the user sees the page the php will have already executed.

Comment: Based on what you're trying to do, probably javascript is better? Are you just trying to make it so when you click on some kind of link, text appears on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code:
In HTML I give class to link...

```
 ...<li><a href="#" class="ajaxtrigger">Edit</a></li>...
```

In space where I want to change text I add this tag:

```
<div id='target'></div>";
```

And at the bottom of document I add this script.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#target').load(url);
      return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not regard only function calling in PHP.
For what you are trying to do you will need Javascript and/or Jquery, AJAX, etc, for the behaviour you are trying to achieve occurs AFTER the page is already loaded (php has already run).

Comment: this only solves his problem if he needs the page to change without refreshing. But if that isn't an issue than this solution is less than ideal for his problem.

Comment: It is what i want... can you take me advice to how to do it? Some examples or ebooks or very good websites? Thank you ;)

Comment: Ok, I just posted another answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP functions for this. You are trying to switch pages and content without creating new files this is easily done using URL variables and the $_GET function in PHP. If you want the page to change content without refreshing then you need to us AJAX and should look into jQuery. Write the PHP code like this

```
<?php
$p = $_GET['p'];

if($p == "one"){
   echo "Something";
}

elseif($p == "two"){
   echo "something else";
} 
else{
    echo'
     THIS IS MY SITE
     <ul>
        <li><a href="'.$_SERVER("PHP_SELF").'?p=one">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="'.$_SERVER("PHP_SELF").'?p=two">TWO</a></li>
     </ul>
';
}

?>
```

or use javascript:

```
     <ul>
        <li><a href="" onClick="show_one();">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onClick="show_two();">TWO</a></li>
     </ul>
<script>
  function show_one(){
    print "SOMETHING";
  } 

  function show_two(){
    print "SOMETHING ELSE";
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: The problem with your first solution is that it won't work if the OP wants the user to be able to have both shown at once

Comment: He didn't specify that is what he wanted so its not a problem if he wants both than he needs to use the second one but its better to just switch the pages with PHP url variables

Answer (score 0):

just pass the function name in an argument and do a switch to see which function to execute
here is an example :

```
echo'
     THIS IS MY SITE
     <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?function=show_one">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?function=show_two">TWO</a></li>
     </ul>
';

if (isset($_GET['function']))
{
   switch($_GET['function'])
   {
        case 'show_one':
         echo "SOMETHING";
        break;

        case 'show_two':
         echo "SOMETHING ELSE";
        break;
   }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo'
     THIS IS MY SITE
     <ul>
        <li><a href="?show_string=one">ONE</a></li>
        <li><a href="?show_string=two">TWO</a></li>
     </ul>
';
$show_string="";

if(!empty($_GET['show_string']))
{
    $show_string=$_GET['show_string'];
}

echo $show_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<script>
  function show_one() {
    document.getElementById("ONE").innerHTML = 'SOMETHING';
  } 

  function show_two() {
    document.getElementById("TWO").innerHTML = 'SOMETHING ELSE';
  } 
</script>
THIS IS MY SITE
<ul>
    <li><a id="ONE" href="#" onClick="show_one();">ONE</a></li>
    <li><a id="TWO" href="#" onClick="show_two();">TWO</a></li>
</ul>
```